# Why is there no output when I click 'run' in ipython notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Intermittently, I'll be running a notebook and clicking 'Run' will suddenly appear to stop doing anything.

The code cells produce no print output, but just bounce me into the next cell. Here is what happens:

[image]

The only clue in the kernel is this message (from a few hours ago, not repeated since then, so I'm not sure if it's connected or not):

```
[W 21:03:01.152 NotebookApp] Notebook analysis.ipynb is not trusted
```

How can I stop this happening? Is my only option to reboot the notebook?

Comment: Do you have the same issue after issuing the following command in your terminal? `ipython trust /path/to/notebook.ipynb`

Comment: I am having the same problem here: I go to https://try.jupyter.org/ and I click on the 'Welcome to Python" file, and then try running the code there according to the instructions there:  nothing happens ... just goes to the next cell like you show in your video.